# array of sockets in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sockets

I want to do an array of socket in perl and add a `\n`, at the end of each socket, I try with `&socket[0]` but it doesn't work.

```
my @socket1;
$socket1[0] = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Type     => SOCK_STREAM,
    PeerAddr => "127.0.0.1",
    Proto    => "tcp",
    PeerPort => $dbase_param{camera_stream}
) or die "Cannot open socket on port " . $dbase_param{camera_stream} . ".\n";

print $socket1[0] "\n";
```

when I do the `print $socket1[0] "\n";` it will not compile.

but if I don't use an array it works :

```
my $socket1;
$socket1 = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Type     => SOCK_STREAM,
    PeerAddr => "127.0.0.1",
    Proto    => "tcp",
    PeerPort => $dbase_param{camera_stream}
) or die "Cannot open socket on port " . $dbase_param{camera_stream} . ".\n";

print $socket1 "\n";
```

Comment: `@cppcoder` No because if I do `print $socket1[0]."\n";` it will print the `socket1[0]` and then a `"\n"` but i want to add in the socket the `"\n"`.

Comment: Secondary Note:  I recommend not adding newlines `\n` to the end of your `die` messages as that will hide the line number information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print`'s filehandle needs to be a glob or a simple scalar (possibly the result of a BLOCK).  This should work:

```
print { $socket1[1] } "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following syntax:

```
$socket1[0]->print("\n");
```

Comment: Use as an `IO::Handle` subclass is always nicer than the weird indirect-object syntax

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `syswrite()` or `send()`. Furthermore this is more recommended interface to work with sockets, because this functions doesn't use buffering. And since you are using IO::Socket::INET object, all this functions are available as methods

```
$socket[1]->print("\n");
$socket[1]->syswrite("\n");
$socket[1]->send("\n");
```